# Stretching axes in perspbox - 3D Plots in R

Tags: r, plot, plot3d

I have been trying to replicate a 3D graph that I saw on a paper that I read for a class project. I recently posted a question asking about possible ways of plotting it and I received amazing support on that. However, I am still struggling to figure out how to stretch the axes to get rid of the cluttering of the values on the axes (image below).

[image]

The code that I used is as follows.

```
library(plot3D)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

R_0 <- function(beta_s, gamma_a, alpha_a = 0.4775, alpha_u = 0.695,
                mu = 0.062, q_i = 0.078, eta_i = 0.009, eta_u = 0.05) {
  
  A <- beta_s * alpha_a / (gamma_a + mu) 
  B <- beta_s * alpha_u * gamma_a * (1 - q_i) / ((gamma_a + mu) * (eta_u + mu))
  A + B
}

beta <- gamma <- seq(0, 0.4, length.out = 100)

R <- outer(beta, gamma, R_0)

#Adding an empty perspbox

perspbox(beta, gamma, z = R, theta = -50, ticktype = "detailed",
         col.grid = "gray85", bty = "u",
         xlab = "\u03b2\u209b", ylab = "\u03b3\u2090")

pp <- persp3D(beta, gamma, z = R, theta = -50, add = TRUE)

#Horizontal plane-adding function

plane3D <- function(z, 
                    col = adjustcolor("blue", alpha.f = 0.2),
                    border = NA,
                    xlim = c(0,0.4), ylim = c(0, 0.4)) {
  dd <- expand.grid(x=xlim, y = ylim, z= z)
  rr <- with(dd, trans3D(x,y,z,pp))
  perm <- c(1,3,4,2)
  polygon(rr$x[perm], rr$y[perm], col = col, border = border)
}

#Adding planes

plane3D(1)
plane3D(2, col = adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.2))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

The graph based on dcarlson's answer

[image]

Comment: Your code does not produce a plot identical to the one you posted. The font size of the values on the axes are much smaller (and not crowded) when I run your code. There is also a type in "\u03b2\u209b" and your margins are too small. Are you printing the plot to a device other than the console?

Comment: Hi dcarlson, thanks for the comment! I am printing the plot to the console and not to any other device. Eventhough I tried removing the part, (xlab = "\u03b2\u209b", ylab = "\u03b3\u2090"), it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code with two changes: `xlab = "\u03b2\u2090"` instead of `xlab = "\u03b2\u209b"` and changing `par(mar=c(1.5, 2, 1.5, 2))` on Mac, I get this plot:

[image: Plot]

You need to provide more information on your computer's operating system and the versions of R  and plot3D that you are using.

Comment: Platform:  x86_64-w64-mingw32, R version: 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt), Version of plot3D: 1.4, Operation system: Windows 11

Comment: Hi dcarlson, thank you so much! I made the suggested changes, and it improved things to a considerable extent. I will put the new graph as an edit. Thanks again!